# xbox 360 flash drive problem

Tags: xbox-360

When I put my flash drive in the Xbox it shows like a normal flash. However, no data can be read when I put a flash in. It is configured before but still no data can be read.

How do I make it show like a configured flash? I don't know how configure it.

I only want to copy a file from my computer to my Xbox by going to the flash drive on PC and go to the Xbox 360 folder and replace `Data 0001` and `0002`.

So can I do this?

This is a picture of what I mean:
[image: Xbox 360 flash drive showing completely empty]

Comment: just a guess...  did you format the usb drive on your PC before trying to use it in the 360?  If yes, I'd work in reverse.  The 360 only understands FAT32 file systems (hence why you can see the device but can't read or write to it), format the USB stick in the 360 first.  Go to "Y" device options and select format.  This will wipe the usb drive clean, but it should now be readable by the 360 and your PC.